# Getting rid of paragraph identation after a figure

Tags: floats, indentation

I'm writing my thesis with ShareLaTeX and is having a problem. For some weird reason, I now have a random indentation at the beginning of a paragraph under a float. I have used numoures floats before and not had a single issue, so I don't know what causes this. Any ideas on how I can solve it?

[image]

Comment: in what way is that random (or connected to the float) you have inserted a blank line which denotes a paragraph break, so the following text starts a new paragraph. Isn't that what is expected? (note that `[H]` means that the environment is not a float, but the paragraph indentation is not related to the figure at all)

Comment: Removing the blanks doesn't work.

Comment: You should always post code as text, as an example that people can debug. No one can debug a screenshot of your code. But the indentation you show is not related to the figure environment, if you remove that environment you will see identical indentation.  You are probably best to use a float here, remove the blank lines and use `[htp]` not `[H]`

Comment: Please also tell us more about your paragraph indentation settings. E.g., has the indentation amount been reset somewhere, maybe in the preamble, e.g., to zero? Please advise.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i think the problem here is that paragraph indentations after floats are unwanted, even if paragraphs are indented elsewhere. This is a common requirement even among publishers.

Comment: you could use `\noindent` at the beginning of this paragraph, e.g. `\noindent <some text here>`.

Comment: @Lupino `[H]` is not a float so you could use `\noindent` but not indenting after a (real) float makes no sense and is very hard to do in latex, floats are not part of the main document flow and are re-inserted after page breaking is decided so well after line breaking and paragraph indents are fixed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i know. We get this all the time, you insert \noindent, author makes a correction that changes the page break and you redistribute the noindents all over again… A general solution would be a nice thing. Overdefining \@outputpage, mabye ;) ?

Comment: surely the correct solution is just to mark the beginning of paragraphs, any use of `\noindent` in a document is a sign that something is wrong.  If you really want it, then it is "safe" here as the H figure is part of the document flow, but using `\noindent` after a floating environment would make no sense at all as the float will move and the `\noindent` will be in the wrong place.